# Hidden VM Azure Marketplace deployment

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace, azure-billing-api

Is having a VM set to 'Hidden' within the cloud partner portal the suggested method for adding billing functionality to an Azure application offer in the marketplace? Can anyone give us guidance for this? We can't find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hiding your VM is the correct way to publish your customized VM being used in the Azure application offer. Please see this doc as well as the associated publishing docs for VMs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal-orig/cloud-partner-portal-solution-template-offer-publish

Comment: Also this question and others like it, are best asked on the partner community forum! Here - https://microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/Marketplace/bd-p/2222